# Why is this such use of generic and wildcard not allowed?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, super

This code

```
static void writeTo(List<? super Apple> apples) {
        apples.add(new Apple());
        apples.add(new Jonathan());
    }
```

The author of this code stated that

> The argument apples is a List of some type that is the base type of Apple; thus you know that it is safe to add an Apple or a subtype of Apple. Since the lower bound is Apple,

Jonathan is a subclass of Apple.

But when I tried this

```
    List<Jonathan> loj = new ArrayList<Jonathan>();
    listSuper(loj);
```

It gave me this error

```
The method listSuper(List<? super Apple>) in the type Basket<T> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Jonathan>)
```

Where `listSuper` looks like this

```
static void listSuper (List<? super Apple> cont) {}
```

How does the two differ?

Also what confuses me on the first code that I posted is that
I thought ? super T means that any base type of T. but from the looks of it he added a subtype of T. I am confused.

Comment: Could't understand the question. Both functions seem to have the same signature. What is the problem?

Comment: @vainolo I added a little information about the error. please do check it out

Comment: [Producer Extends, Consumer Super](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs/2723538#2723538)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List<? super Apple>` means a `List` you can add an `Apple` to (and since `Jonathan` *is an* `Apple`, you can put `Jonathan`s into a `List` of that type as well).

It can be `List<Apple>`, `List<Fruit>` or `List<Object>`, but not `List<Jonathan>`, since you cannot put arbitrary `Apple`s into `List<Jonathan>`. As you can see, in this case `?` can be an `Apple` or any of its superclasses.

`List<? extends Apple>` means a `List` you can get an `Apple` from. It can be `List<Apple>` or `List<Jonathan>`, but not `List<Fruit>`, since `List<Fruit>` is not guaranteed to contain only `Apple`s.

This explanation is known as "producer - `extends`, consumer - `super`" rule: if parameter acts as a consumer of elements, it should be declared with `super`, and vice versa.

Comment: but how come he added a Jonathan object inside a List ? super Apple

Comment: @KyelJmD: Updated. `Jonathan` is an `Apple`, therefore you can put it into a `List` that can contain `Apple`s.

Answer (score 4):

`Jonathan` is a subtype of `Apple`, not a supertype. It would match `<? extends Apple>` but does not match `<? super Apple>`

Comment: But how come he added  a Jonathan inside the a list of apples? in the writeTo method?

Comment: There is no problem adding an instance of `Jonathan` to a `List<Apple>`, why would there be? That is totally different to what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

The author of the code was wrong. You can't pass a subclass of Apple to a method that takes ? super Apple, only Apple itself and superclasses of Apple. If you want to be able to add subclasses of Apple, you need to use ? extends Apple.

Comment: You are wrong, read the top answers. A list of type ? super Apple can take Apple and all its subtypes. A list of type ? extends Apple cannot have anything added to it at all, but you are always getting apples from it.

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter must be a *supertype* of Apple, not a *subclass*, which is what `Jonathan` is. So, for instance, this would be valid:

```
List<Fruit> loj = new ArrayList<Fruit>();     
listSuper(loj);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does the two differ?
>
> Also what confuses me on the first code that I posted is that I
>   thought ? super T means that any base type of T. but from the looks of
>   it he added a subtype of T. I am confused.

You must distinguish between (1) what you can insert into a generic list and (2) what can be sent as an argument to method with a generic list parameter.

1. You can insert subtypes of `Apple` into `apples` because the bound type parameter is a base class which has the ability to reference all its subtypes.
2. If `Jonathan` isn't a super type of `Apple`, then it's generically incorrect to try and send a list of `Jonathan` to that method, since I'd be allowed to insert `Apple`s into a list of `Jonathan`s. Then you'd have references of type `Jonathan` accessing the properties and methods of objects it knows nothing about, which isn't type-safe.